# Updating Contact Owner for All Records Using Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, contact, ownership

I have a small database of about 300 `contacts` and my company is looking to implement a new mapping system to assign each `contact` to a sales rep.

After I have exported the data, cleaned up any duplicates, and assigned each a sales rep based on our new system how do I load the records back into production using the sandbox in order to update the contact owner field with the changes for all of the records at one time?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean, 'load the records back into production using the sandbox'?  Do you mean you have the sandbox Ids of the sales reps, but they obviously don't work in production?

Comment: I'm basically manually changing the assignment on sales reps to my 300 contacts.  So is there a way to export the data and change the field entry for each record manually in excel then upload it to the Sandbox and push the changes to Production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I didn't fully understand your question for a few reasons.

However, I think I know the question that you mean to ask:

"**How can I insert the cleaned up contact data into sandbox (to test it), and then after my colleagues are happy with how it looks in sandbox, how can I insert this data into production?**"

**High level summary**
As per leylandski's answer: Use the data loader to insert data into the Salesforce org that you want.

**(Much) more detailed summary**

1. You can use a free extract-transfer-load tool called the Apex Data Loader to achieve this. (To get this tool, go to your production org and in Setup, search for 'Data Management').

There are many other tools that can also be used (just go to the Salesforce appexchange). But the Data Loader is the general standard and works well.

2. Have your data file formatted correctly (.csv format) with all the columns representing the field names and ensure any fields that require an Id are populated with Ids.

For example, you can't simply map a record to the Sales Rep Name column, you must map the record to the User Id of the Sales Rep. (So the assumption here is that all the sales reps are Salesforce users).

3. Login into the Data Loader.

When you use the Data Loader to insert data, you specify the org you want the data to be inserted into. To do this, you input your Salesforce credentials (password and username). Be sure to change the URL from https://login.salesforce.com to https://test.salesforce.com if you are inserting data into sandbox. And of course, make sure that sandbox username is input correctly (the sandbox org name must be at the end of your username).

4. Choose a DML operation (you want to do an Insert).
5. Choose an object (you want to select Contact).

You will also notice that all your custom objects are available to be selected. Different Data Loaders have different API versions. The most current Data Loader will be API version 35, I think. If a new Data Loader version comes out, and then you create a custom object, you won't be able to access that custom object via a Data Loader that uses a previous API version.

6. Save a location for the Success / Error files

When you use the Data Loader for any DML operation, two files are returned. Be sure to specify a location for these files. If there are no errors returned, the error file will be blank. The Data Loader stores the last returned Success and Error files too. Just go to Settings in the Data Loader file and you will see an option to view the Success / Error files.

7. Specify the mapping

This means to map the columns in your .csv file to the Salesforce fields of the object you selected. If a column in your .csv file is called 'Owner', you will want to map that column to the 'OwnerId' field in the Data Loader. Your .csv file should reference the Account Ids of the contacts will relate to (best practice to have contacts linked to the respective account). If you have multiple contact record type Ids, you will need to make sure you specify the correct one per record too. If you don't, the default record type Id will be used.

If you have any validation rules that are hit from attempting the DML operation you specified, the records that hit the validation rules will fail. In the returned Error file, the fail reason will be at the column furthest to the right. If any validation rule is hit, then the validation error message will be specified in that column, so at least it is easy to identify what the issue is.

Also, make sure that any mandatory field on the contact object is populated else you will return an error for those records.

You can either select 'auto map' in the Data Loader, which assumes you have fairly correctly labelled your columns in your .csv file. For example, if you named a column 'AccountId' or 'Account', then the Data Loader will automatically map that column to the corresponding Salesforce field of that object.

Else, you can choose to do a manual mapping.

You can save your mapping too, and use that again for another similar insert, if that's required.

That was probably more comprehensive than it needed to be but I hope those tips help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Salesforce Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader) might be what you're looking for. It can take CSV files with records in and insert, update, upsert, or merge them with your instance.

Best practice is to test with 2 or 3 records first before mass-uploading the rest in case you've overlooked something.